# Quarkus Logging - UseParentHandler Does Not Work

Tags: quarkus

I tried to use "useParentHandlers" to prevent the logs (defined by class / category) from being propagated across multiple files. That is, the same message in several different files.
Example:

```
quarkus:
  log:
    category:
         "a.b.c.d":
            handlers: ABCD_FILE
            useParentHandlers: false
            level: INFO
    
          "a.b":
            handlers: AB_LOG_FILE
            useParentHandlers: false
            level: INFO
```

However, some messages appear in both.
"a.b.c.d" message appears in "a.b"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration properties are transformed with dashes. So you need to use `use-parent-handlers`.

Did you find `useParentHandlers` somewhere in our documentation? If so, can you point it to me? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/10351 . Thanks for reporting.